# Custom getter not called in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create a getter for a property - for the time being I'm just using the method to build up an NSMutableObject from static arrays but eventually these will be dynamic config settings. In a previous app and from [getter and setters not working objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838852/getter-and-setters-not-working-objective-c) I did this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *questions;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[self questions] setValue:@"FOO" forKey:@"bar"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)questions
{
    static NSMutableDictionary *_questions;
    if (_questions== nil)
    {
        NSArray *genders = @[@"male", @"female"];
        NSArray *ages = @[@"<10", @">60", @"Other"];
        _questions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_questions setValue:genders forKey:@"gender"];
        [_questions setValue:ages forKey:@"age"];

    }

    return _questions;
}
```

When I get to the line in viewDidLoad where I try to use the 'questions' property, it doesn't use the custom getter (it just assigns bar:FOO to a nil dictionary). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)questions
```

To

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)questions
```

You may also want to change the return type to `NSDictionary *` to prevent the static variable from being mutated, or return `_questions.copy` or `_questions.mutableCopy`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your custom `questions` method is not being called through `setValue:forKey:` is that it is a class method:

`+ (NSMutableDictionary *)questions` is a method defined on the `ViewController` class, while the property accessor (which `setValue:forKey:` is looking for) is defined on the *instance*.

To access your custom method as it is currently defined call the class method:

`[[[self class] questions] setValue:@"FOO" forKey:@"bar"];`

This may not have the effect you intend, as this value will be shared across all instances of the class.

Comment: Indeed, I suspect that the OP meant to make it an instance method: ` (NSMutableDictionary *)questions` (Change the leading "+" to a "-"